# Adsense link ads (or ad links) with responsive website

Tags: responsive-design, adsense

Responsive adsense ads are working fine on my responsive website but I would also like to add horizontal "ad links" to the website (to be shown only on desktop due to higher width).

So, what I want to do is place 728x15 ad link unit in the responsive site and make them visible only for large screens (read desktop). However, as per adsense policy, changing ads through media queries is allowed only in responsive ad units (through display: none) but there are no responsive ad for "ad links".

Any ideas how can I implement adsense "ad links" in a responsive website so these link ads are shown only on larger screens (say for min-width:800) without violating adsense policies.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far I can see `display:none` method for not showing AdSense ad, *does* work with (asynchronous) link units and I think [it does work for all *asynchronous* AdSense units](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/PM3zRWUR3Oc/NQfweBKsCP0J). (For every AdSense snippet with `adsbygoogle.js` in `script src`.)

But, you are right: AdSense Help Center is not mentioning "asynchronous" and it explicitly says "[Hiding ad units at anytime (e.g., display:none), unless you're implementing a **responsive** ad unit](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354736?hl=en)".

My wild guess is that might be because there are already `@media` queries in original responsive code (code you get from the AdSense dashboard), and the risk of error and the number of modifications are minimal:

1. [removing inline `style` attribute from `ins` tag](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense-es/SWFoOwCcYIM/xGJ71bsmsZkJ)
2. updating "default" class declaration block in `style` tag ("first line")
3. applying `display:none` on `ins` tag via custom class (`.adlinkunit1` in example below)

So this should work for you ("*link ads are shown only on larger screens (say for min-width:800)*":

```
<style type="text/css">
.adlinkunit1 { display:inline-block;width:728px;height:15px }
@media ( max-width: 800px) { .adlinkunit1 { display: none; } }
</style>
<ins class="adsbygoogle adlinkunit1"
  data-ad-client="ca-pub-..."
  data-ad-slot="..."></ins>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>
```

(Please note `max-width` is used for `display:none`.)

Personally I think above example is not a violation of the AdSense policies, but also I'm not sure why Help Center says "responsive" and of course - what will happen if Google would ever decide (for some reason) to remove (undocumented) `display:none` support from non-responsive asynchronous units.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I also wanted to implement the link ads the way you just described but I wanted to be sure it doesn't violate the adsense policy. Anyway, I have dropped an email to adsense folks to be doubly sure...I will update the post for everyone's benefit once I receive their reply. Thanks again!

Comment: Did you ever get a reply?

Comment: Yes, I did get a reply but it was kinda ambiguous as they called the linkad as responsive. I didn't followup and implemented as suggested by @galeksic 

Reply >> Since this is a responsive ad and you do want to hide the ad unit for smaller screens, you can set a parameter with CSS media queries so that no ad request is made and no ad is shown.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try a "device detection" solution like WURFL cloud, which at the time of writing this costs $40p.m.

With that solution, you can get things like "IS_DESKTOP" and "IS_MOBILE" and "IS_TABLET".

From there you can really customise your ads to your different devices. For example, on the desktop you can display the 728x15 block, and on mobiles you can display something smaller like 200x90, meaning you're not missing out on possible mobile based revenue.

It also allows you to test different ad blocks on different devices really well... what works best on tablets? Is it 728x15 or 468x15. Or what about normal ad blocks (not ad links) on mobile devices, is it text only, or image, or both? Does an ads perform better in different positions on different devices?

You can get really granular with this approach in an easily maintainable way. If you have a decent amount of traffic to your website you shouldn't have a problem making more than an extra $40p.m in adsense revenue, mitigating the cost of using a service like WURFL cloud (and no, I am in no way affiliated with then, it's just a solution I use, partially based upon my desire to have an easily maintainable way to get really granular with my adsense on different devices).

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

A solution called WURFL.js allows you to leverage WURFL at no cost (community edition)

http://wurfl.io

The same framework with more WURFL properties and more features is available though the Business Edition of the same tool. To avoid doubt, I am affiliated with ScientiaMobile, the company that offers these tools.